# Generic function with Mono inheritance WebFlux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have the following abstract parent class (contains an abstract method returning a generic type),

```
abstract class Parent {
    abstract Mono<List<? extends ClassA>> function(ClassB classB);
}
```

and the following child class (ClassC extends ClassA, implement the generic function with specific type).

```
class Child extends Parent {
    @Override
    public Mono<List<ClassC>> function(ClassB classB) {
        // business logic returning the correct type
    }
}
```

The IDE shows an error saying the functions are clashing. When Mono is removed, the error is no longer there. Could someone please tell how this can be done correctly?

Comment: Isn't a `Mono<LIst>` a bit weird? Shouldn't that be a `Flux<? extends ClassA>>` in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for checking, I am using Mono to wrap a blocking call - https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking

Comment: You can convert the list to a flux, can you show the implementation also could you add the error/warning you get?

Comment: I don't think the implementation matters as the error is happening even when I am just returning `Mono.just(new LinkedList<>());`.

Comment: The error is that function in class Parent clashes with function in class Child.

Comment: Using a `Flux` reduces the level of generics, which could help and a `Mono<List>` feels weird/wrong in a reactive context. Hence the suggestion. It basically then is the same as `List<ClassC>` which, according to yourself, did work.

Comment: I would suggest turning the class Parent into Generic class like Parent<? extends ClassA>, then Child could extend Parent<ClassC>.

Comment: M. Deinum - Thanks, using a flux instead of mono list worked. Mustafa Khalil - Thanks, but could you please tell why generic class instead of generic method alone is required here?